# Drools 6.5 take more time to build the KieBase

Tags: java, drools

i am working to upgrade my project from drools 6.1 to 6.5 and I am having problem that **KieBase** take more time to build

the below line of code take more time .. could you please help on this issue

```
KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSys).buildAll();
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about the number of DRL files and their LOC, and the number of rules. - Do you always need to re-build all files?

Comment: no, just i am building one time for each request. the problem is that in drools 6.1 we where able to serialize the drools and then deserialize it by adding the rules to the package then generate one rulebase ..... now with new drools, you can't add the rules to the KieBase package .... thats why i ran into this issue ... could you please help me with this ...thanks

Comment: How many DRL files? Lines? Rules? - Why do you build each time? You can build once and use the KieBase for creating any number of sessions.

Comment: we have 200+ DRL files and 1000+ rules ... i dont build each time just i build one KieBase and use the session .. but the problem is building the KieBase is taking long time >3 sec for each KieBase.

Comment: i am using kieFileSys.write(myPathName, kieServices.getResources().newReaderResource(new StringReader(content))); to keep writing the DRL file and then build the kieBase. but the build line take more time and performing slowly

Comment: That's five rules per file on average, which is unusual. Reducing the number of files might improve the situation. -- But why are you reading the files into a String before writing them to the KieFileSystem?

Comment: because we do encrypt all the drools file and then we start decrypted the DRL then add it to the KieBase. so, i actually i can just read as byteArray but the problem is that in Drools 6.1 we were able to add the DRL files to one RuleBase then we serialize it and then we Desialize it and use it to RuleBase and then fire the Rule ..... but, i could not find any way to do the same in the Drools 6.5 because i could not add the package in the new Drools 6.5.. i am really sticking with this issue for two weeks and we need to be in production soon :(

Comment: Unclear. Why do you need many files and encryption. If the user provides the rules you don't need encryption. If your company provides them for your customers, <ou can compile on your premises and deploy the compiled KieBase.

Comment: @Moe were you able to resolve this issue ? I'm also intermittently facing this issue where same line taking 9-10 sec. In my case number of files and rules are very less (< 10). ? Pls guide if you resolved. TIA.

Comment: @apandey846, any luck with this? I am facing the same issue. Thx.